# Threads Execution

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it possible to know when the thread has completed its execution without using any of the builtin function like isAlive, join.
Suppose we have 3 threads A, B and C running in parallel. So how to know whether all the threads have completed their execution.

Comment: Why would you want to use something other than `join`?

Comment: Can we use an `if`, or is that too built-in?

Comment: An alternative might be, given that a thread ends its execution after run() method returns... to flag the end of that. Still, what is your goal?

Comment: @shmosel. You can use if. But  not to use functions like isAlive, join,etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use CountDownLatch to help you out with it. 
Let's say you're making threads with ExecutorService, so you could make something like

```
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(threadsCount);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadsCount);

        for (int x = 0; x < threadsCount; x++)
        {
            executor.submit(new ClassName(latch));
        }
        try
        {
            latch.await();
        }
        catch (Exception ignored){} 
//all threads are done at this point
```

And in your ClassName you should have something like this:

```
class ClassName implements Runnable
{
    private CountDownLatch latch;

    //constructor:
    ClassName(CountDownLatch latch)
    {
         this.latch = latch;
    }

    //run method:
    @Override
    void run()
    {
        //Your thread code...

        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

So in your run-method in ClassName, you need to call latch.countDown().

CountDownLatch is automatically syncronized, so you don't need to think about that.

You don't need to use ExectuorService in order to use Latch, this was just an example.

Comment: threadsCount is obviously an Integer that represents the number of threads by the way.

Comment: If they are really asking about _when the thread has completed its execution_, this won't do it, especially not with an `ExecutorService` that maintains the same thread for multiple `Runnable`s.

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, or what you actually mean. If you want to know when a thread basically is finished doing it's job, this actually will work.

Comment: Your answer is more about the task, not the thread. A thread completing can only be detected through `join` and `isAlive`. Everything else is a race condition at best.

Comment: Thanks @Pillar. Actually i got this question from my friend and i answered the same like using isAlive and join. But he told me to use some logic for example using loops until all the thread has completed then return to the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you're practically asking for bad ideas, here's a backwards, nondeterministic solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("t1"));
    t1.start();
    WeakReference<Thread> r1 = new WeakReference<Thread>(t1);
    t1 = null;

    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("t2"));
    t2.start();
    WeakReference<Thread> r2 = new WeakReference<Thread>(t2);
    t2 = null;

    while (r1.get() != null || r2.get() != null) {
        System.gc();
    }

    System.out.println("done!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But its not a bad idea. Some people may get questions like this. And my friend got this question in interview

Comment: @userLearning, in that case, here's your answer. Though it's much likelier the question was how to check if the *task* completed, as per user1478293's answer.